# Difference between ListResultDto and List

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

In my application service, why should I return `ListResultDto` instead of returning `List`?

It seems like extra work.

On the frontend, it means I need to access the `items` property instead of treating the results as an array e.g.

**Using `ListResultDto`**

```
.subscribe((next) => this.entities = next.items);
```

**Using `List`**

```
.subscrube((next) => this.entities = next);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`ListResultDto`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/a6c25c2352ab95ab956b8f26e5a4840fb43b0e1d/src/Abp/Application/Services/Dto/ListResultDto.cs) allows you to add additional information about your `items` in the future without breaking your existing API. If you return `items` as an array, you are restricting your API.

An example is `TotalCount` in [`PagedResultDto`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/cbc100d2e4dad8fb1927fa71a8b3182f77d30481/src/Abp/Application/Services/Dto/PagedResultDto.cs), if you want to implement pagination of `items`.